# How to read data from XML response that have '@' symbol in php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, api

I'm trying to read the response from cURL execution. The response is in XML format. I'm using simplexml_load_string function. The response has a @ symbol in the object.

I tried simplexml_load_file($resp) but getting error in that.

Below is the reponse when I do dd()

```
SimpleXMLElement {#891 ▼
  +"GUID": SimpleXMLElement {#900 ▼
    +"@attributes": array:3 [▼
      "GUID" => "dasdavdf3423rfgert34r"
      "SUBMITDATE" => "2019-07-30 00:27:16"
      "ID" => "1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Through above reponse I tried $xml_resp->GUID->@attributes[0]->GUID but I'm getting error at @ symbol

I need to fetch GUID.

Comment: It's an attribute, so try https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes of SimpleXMLElement can be accessed with `[]`:

```
echo $xml_resp->GUID['GUID'];
```